# error de stripe con php

Tags: php, composer, stripe

tardes o noches, he estado trabajando con la extensión de stripe y me di cuenta que tiene varios problemas al menos la carpeta de server algunos ya los resolví pero otros, como es en este caso, no se como proceder mi carpeta de trabajo es esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando lo pongo en servidor me aparece esto:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Dotenv\Dotenv" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\pagina_stps\stps\stripe\accept-a-payment\server\public\shared.php:30 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pagina_stps\stps\stripe\accept-a-payment\server\public\shared.php on line 30
```

voy a la linea 30 del archivo shared.php y dice esto:

```html
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__ . '/..');
```

no es la primera vez que este archivo me marca error antes tuve que añadir una dirección del composer por que la carpeta donde esta el proyecto de stripe esta dentro de otra carpeta y a su vez el php esta dentro de servidor así que tuve que hacer unos cambios ligeros al menos en el require queda asi (pongo toda una sección ya que tengo duda igual acerca del dominio

```html
<?php
$HOME=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
define("RAIZ", $HOME);
require RAIZ .'/pagina_stps/stps/vendor/autoload.php';


// If the .env file was not configured properly, display a helpful message.
if(!file_exists(RAIZ .'/pagina_stps/stps/stripe/accept-a-payment/server/.env')) {
  ?>
  <h1>Missing <code>.env</code></h1>

  <p>Make a copy of <code>.env.example</code>, place it in the same directory as composer.json, and name it <code>.env</code>, then populate the variables.</p>
  <p>It should look something like the following, but contain your <a href='https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys'>API keys</a>:</p>
  <pre>STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test...
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=sk_test...
STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET=whsec_...
DOMAIN=http://localhost:4242</pre>
  <hr>

  <p>You can use this command to get started:</p>
  <pre>cp .env.example .env</pre>

  <?php
  exit;
}
```

noten que al menos al principio habia un require con un ../vendor/autoload.php sin embargo se tuvo que cambiar por

```
    $HOME=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
define("RAIZ", $HOME);
require RAIZ .'/pagina_stps/stps/vendor/autoload.php';
```

para mayor facilidad de redirección aqui mi pregunta es con el fatal error ya que no se q procede o como resolverlo alguna idea... gracias de antemano

Comment: Parece que tu instalación de _Stripe_ está incompleta y le faltan dependencias. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66808846/2412893) (en inglés), aunque el repositorio que menciona ya no está disponible, pero te puede servir de guía para buscar la solución.

Comment: muchas gracias deja lo checo entonces :)